# CollectionUtils import in play template

Tags: playframework-2.0

My template *menu.scala.html* is as follows

```
@(menuItems: List[utils.MenuUtils.IMenuItem])

@import org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils

@if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(menuItems)) {
    <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
        @for(menuItem <- menuItems) {
            <li>
                <a @if(menuItem.isActive()) {class = "active"} href="@{menuItem.getUrl()}">@{menuItem.getLabel()}</a>
            </li>
        }
        </ul>
    </div>
}
```

and the compiler says:

> object collections is not a member of package org.apache.commons in ..\menu.scala.html at line 2

Does anybody see any error here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

commons-collections is scoped as a test dependency (probably because it is a transitive dependency to some of the test libraries), so you need to add it as a normal dependency in your project sbt config to be able to use it.